# The type org.eclipse.core.runtime.IConfigurationElement cannot be resolved.

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I wanted to create an Eclipse plugin like in this tutorial:
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/viewArticle/ViewArticle2.html

[There was a screenshot here, but I cant post images]  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PWDQ.png

But in the first line of LabelView.java I get this error:

"The type org.eclipse.core.runtime.IConfigurationElement cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".
[The Second error is: The hierarchy of the type LabelView is inconsistent]

I checked the olugin.xml but it seems to be OK..

[The xml file posted as code here got ”not properly formatted as code” error, so check]!
i.stack.imgur.com/2EhNQ.png

Somebody knows how to get rid of this error?

using
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

Comment: add eclipse plugin path to the project `classpath`.

Comment: This article is very old, specifying plugin dependencies using `<requires>` was deprecated some time ago. Try opening the plugin.xml with the Eclipse "Plug-in Manifest" editor and click `Update the classpath settings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot!

**greg-449** is right!

At plugin.xml overview was a massage about missing Manifest, so on pressing it eclipse created the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file.
Than you just need to "Update the classpath settings".

That's all, the error was gone.